# impossible to display code blocks with Beamer in Latex

Tags: latex, beamer

I have lines of code to display in a presentation with beamer, but as soon as I use the `\begin{lstlisting}` tags in the `\begin{frames}` tags, my document can't compile. But as soon as I put the lstlisting section aside, it displays correctly.
[image: inside the frame tags]

[image: outside the frame tags]

[complete code link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/phktjvdfbgjc#6e981a)

Comment: " [...] it displays correctly. " That's wrong. Your document does not compile, there are many errors in your document, too many to list them all here in comments. If there are errors in the document, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing reasonable output. Even in your screenshot, one can see the missing letters.

Comment: You might want to consider getting a code review, e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or if you prefer a place specific to tex: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?search=review

Comment: In case you prefer to ask in French: https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the `é` in your listing. You can enable them like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    literate={é}{{\'e}}1  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}
    def euler(f, x0, y0, h, n):
        x = np.zeros(n)
        y = np.zeros(n)
        x[0], y[0] = x0, y0
        for i in range(1, n):
            y[i] = y[i-1] + h * f(x[i-1], y[i-1])
            x[i] = x[i-1] + h
        return x, y
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    y = odeint(équation, condition, durée)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]